# Replacing MicrosoftRibbonForWPF with .NET 4.5 integrated Ribbon

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.5, ribbon

I just replaced the Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon with the new System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon and this is ok so far.

But if I maximize my application the window now seems to be slightly too big. So that the upper left icon and the icons in the QuickAccessToolbar are only shown partially.

Is it enough to just replace the Ribbon, or do I have to do more?

You can reproduce this problem by just creating a new WPF application and using RibbonWindow instead of Window as the base class for MainWindow.

BTW: The MainWindow title disappeares when using RibbonWindow.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?